# Confusion about local coordinates of a topological manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Introduction to smooth manifolds by John M.Lee. He has defined that
Let $M$ be a topological n-manifold.A coordinate chart on $M$ is a pair $(U,\phi)$ where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\phi:U\to \bar{U}$ is a homomorphism from $U$ to an open subset $\bar{U}=\phi(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$,and $\phi$ are local coordinate map
We call $U$ a coordinate domain of each of its points.
My Question: After this, he says that the component functions $(x^1,x^2,......,x^n)$ of $\phi$ defined by $\phi(p)=(x^1(p),x^2(p),.....,x^n(p))$ are local coordinate of $U$.What I am confused about here is $U$ itself will have coordinates and here we are talking about local coordinates, can someone explain to me how  $(x^1(p),x^2(p),.....,x^n(p))$ is a local coordinate of $U$? is it because of homeomorphic mapping? Also if you can give some example to visualize that will be great help.Thanks.

Comment: Small (and frequent) misprint: you typed *homomorphism* (form $U$ to an open subset) instead of *homeomorphism*.

Answer (score 3):

Either you misread [that page](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&pg=PA5), or you have an older edition and the misprint has been corrected since.

What I can read is not

> the component functions $(x^1,x^2,......,x^n)$ of $\phi$ defined by $\phi(x^1(p),x^2(p),.....,x^n(p))$

but

> the component functions $(x^1,x^2,......,x^n)$ of $\varphi$, defined by $\varphi(p)=(x^1(p),x^2(p),.....,x^n(p)).$